# Every boolean function is multiplicative with probability greater than $1/2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, boolean-algebra

Let $f:\left\{-1,1\right\}^n\to\left\{-1,1\right\}$.

How to show that
$$
P_{{x,y,z}} \{f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z)\} \ge 1/2?
$$
where $x,y,z$ are distributed uniformly and independently on $\left\{-1,1\right\}^n$.

Equivalently, the set
$$
\{(x,y,z)\in (\left\{-1,1\right\}^n)^3 \,|\,f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z)\}
$$
has at least $2^n\times 2^n\times 2^{n-1}$ elements.

---

I think there should be a simple argument that I am missing.

**Edit:**

I forgot to define:
$$
(xy)_i:=x_iy_i, \,\,\, (xyz)_i:=x_iy_iz_i,
$$
so the product is component-wise.

Comment: The question in the title seems different than the question in the body. The title makes it sound to me like the question is whether at least half of all functions are multiplicative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will reformulate.

Take the space $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ and define the function $u:\mathbb{F}_2^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ via $$f(z)=(-1)^{u(x)}$$ where $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\in \{-1,+1\}^n$ and
$x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in \mathbb{F}_2^n.$ Since all $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ operations are modulo $2,$ and the products of $f$ become sums of $u$ what we desire to show is
$$
\sum_{x,y,z}(-1)^{u(x)+u(y)+u(z)+u(x+y+z)}\geq 0,\qquad(1)
$$
where the sums are over $\mathbb{F}_2^n.$ This is because
$$
f(xyz)=f(x)f(y)f(z) \Leftrightarrow u(x+y+z)=u(x)+u(y)+u(z),
$$
and when the equality holds we pick up a $+1$ in the sum, otherwise we pick up a $-1.$ Now the sum in $(1)$ can be rewritten as
$$
\sum_{x,y}(-1)^{u(x)+u(y)}\sum_{z}(-1)^{u(z)+u(x+y+z)}.
$$
For each fixed $x,y$ letting $a=x+y,$ the inner sum is of the form
$$
\sum_{z}(-1)^{u(z)+u(a+z)},
$$
and when $a=0$ which is the same as $x=y,$ the inner sum takes on the value $2^n$ since the exponent is $2u(z)$ which is zero modulo $2.$ This happens for $2^n$ pairs $(x,y)$ with $y=x.$

When $a\neq 0,$ then we need to treat the sum differently. Let us rewrite the whole sum as
$$
\sum_{x,y:x=y}(-1)^{2u(x)}\sum_{z}(-1)^{2u(z)}+
\sum_{x,y:x\neq y}(-1)^{u(x)+u(y)}\sum_{z}(-1)^{u(z)+u(x+y+z)},
$$
which becomes
$$
2^{2n}+\sum_{x}\sum_{a\neq 0}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}\sum_{z}(-1)^{u(z)+u(a+z)},
$$
or
$$
2^{2n}+\sum_{a\neq 0}\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}\sum_{z}(-1)^{u(z)+u(a+z)},
$$
or
$$
2^{2n}+\sum_{a\neq 0}\left(\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}\right)^2\geq 0,
$$
as required. When $u$ is *linear*, i.e., $$u(x+a)=u(x)+u(a),\quad \forall x,a$$ the second term is actually zero since a linear function is balanced.

Comment: Thanks, that is an ingenious solution! BTWm when the function is linear the second term equals $2^{2n}(2^{n}-1)$, so the whole sum $\sum_{x,y,z}(-1)^{u(x)+u(y)+u(z)+u(x+y+z)}$ equals $2^{3n}$ which makes sense, since all triples $(x,y,z)$ are in the "multiplicative satisfying set".

Comment: BTW, you might be interested in this follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396007/characterising-functions-mathbbf-2n-to-mathbbf-2-satisfying-special-eq

Comment: Very slick! :^)