# Characterising functions $\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2$ satisfying special equations

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, finite-fields, boolean-algebra

Let $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ be the field with two elements, and let
$u:\mathbb{F}_2^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$ be a function.

> Is it possible that
> $$
> \sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}= 0,
> $$
> for every $a \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$?

**If so, can we characterise the functions satisfying property?**

*Comment:* I treat the sum here as natural (or real) number, not as an element of $\mathbb{F}_2$.

---

This question arose in the context of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4395191/every-boolean-function-is-multiplicative-with-probability-greater-than-1-2). (Trying to derive a lower bound on the approximate multiplicativity of a Boolean function).

---

If $u$ is linear, i.e. $u(x+y)=u(x)+u(y)$, then the sum above is never zero.

---

**Edit:**

Jyrki Lahtonen gave a nice example for all even $n$. It turns out that [there are no such functions for odd $n$.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/417477/are-there-functions-mathbbf-2n-to-mathbbf-2-satisfying-these-special-r)

Comment: If $u$ has domain $\mathbb{F}_2^n$, how can you evaluate it at $u(x+a)$ if $x$ is a real or natural number? You need $x+a\in\mathbb{F}_2^n$, and since $a\in\mathbb{F}_2^n$, you have $x\in\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

Comment: You are right. I meant for the sum to go over all $x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$. I tried to say that I treat the sum itself as natural (or real) number, not as an element of $\mathbb{F}_2$. I have stated this more clearly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following idea I borrowed from the theory of so called [bent functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent_function) (that Claude Carlet's group is actively researching) gives a construction of an example of such a function $u$. Assuming that $n$ is an even number.

---

Write $n=2k$, $V=\Bbb{F}_2^k$, and $\langle\ ,\ \rangle:V\times V\to \Bbb{F}_2$ the usual inner product. We identify $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ with $V\times V$ and use $u=\langle\ ,\ \rangle$. Let $(a,b)$ be a non.zero vector of $V\times V$. Let $(x,y)$ be an arbitrary vector. Bilinearity means that
$$
\begin{aligned}
u((x,y))+u((x,y)+(a,b))&=\langle x,y\rangle+\langle x+a,y+b\rangle\\
&=\langle a,y\rangle+\langle x,b\rangle+\langle a,b\rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore the sum
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{(x,y)\in\Bbb{F}_2^n}(-1)^{u((x,y))+u((x,y)+(a,b))}&=
\sum_{x\in V}\sum_{y\in V}(-1)^{\langle a,y\rangle+\langle x,b\rangle+\langle a,b\rangle}\\
&=(-1)^{\langle a,b\rangle}\sum_{y\in V}(-1)^{\langle a,y\rangle}\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{\langle x,b\rangle}.
\end{aligned}
$$
The assumption is that at least one of $a,b$ is non-zero. Therefore at least one of the sums that appear as factors in the final formula vanishes by the usual orthogonality of characters (see below). Hence so does the entire sum.

---

In other words, if $n=2$, use $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$. If $n=4$, use
$u(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_1x_3+x_2x_4$ et cetera.

---

Orthogonality. Assume that $a\in V$ is non-zero. Then there exists an element $\epsilon\in V$ such that $\langle a,\epsilon\rangle=1$. We fix one such. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(a)&:=\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{\langle x,a\rangle}\\
&=\sum_{x+\epsilon\in V}(-1)^{\langle x+\epsilon,a\rangle}\\
&=\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{\langle x+\epsilon,a\rangle}&\text{because $x$ ranges over $V$ while $x+\epsilon$ does}\\
&=(-1)^{\langle\epsilon,a\rangle}\left(\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{\langle x,a\rangle}\right)\\
&=-S(a).
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $S(a)=0$ as claimed.

Comment: Thanks! Can you perhaps elaborate on why $\sum_{y\in V}(-1)^{\langle a,y\rangle}=0$  (if $a \neq 0$)? (If that is not straightforward, than link to relevant reference or terminology to look for would also be welcomed).

Comment: @AsafShachar It is pretty straightforward. And very standard in a variety of contexts. I added an argument to the end.

Comment: Thanks. That is a great answer! It's nice to interact with you again. I remember that you gave me many interesting answers at several times in the past...Thank you very much. I have seen that there are no bent functions for odd $n$ BTW which is interesting. However, I am not sure they are exactly equivalent to the objects stated in this question. So I am not sure whether there are solutions for odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is an area of still active research, as far as I know (errored claim regarding linear functions removed, shouldn't post after midnight).

See the fantastic survey on Boolean functions by Claude Carlet available [here](https://www.math.univ-paris13.fr/%7Ecarlet/chap-fcts-Bool-corr.pdf).

Specifically (p. 59) a function $f$ is said to satisfy the propagation criterion with respect to a set $E\subset \mathbb{F}_2^n$ if the directional derivative
$$
D_a f(x)=f(x)-f(x+a)
$$
is balanced for all $a\in E.$

Your question corresponds to the case
$E=\mathbb{F}_2^n\setminus \{0\}.$

**Update:**

*I am not an expert in this field but know about some of the results.*

If we consider a function
$$
f:\mathbb{F}_{2^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^n} \quad(1)
$$
instead of a boolean function, such a function is called a *planar function* if
$$
D_a f(x)=f(x)-f(x+a)
$$
is a permutation of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ for all nonzero $a$ in $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}.$ Note that by choosing a basis you can view $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ as $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ but some technical issues arise with respect to equivalence of functions.

If you have a planar function, you can compose it with, say, the trace map
$$
tr:\mathbb{F}_{2^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2
$$
which is $2^{n-1}$ to $1$
and obtain a function satisfying the propagation criterion for all $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^n}\setminus \{0\}.$ The planar functions $f$ in $(1)$ are also known as *perfect nonlinear* functions in cryptography which may help you find related results.

Some families of such functions exist but there is no full characterisation as far as I know. See page 79 of the Carlet chapter regarding this topic.

A relatively recent result in this topic, exhibiting monomial planar functions was given in

Schmidt and Zhou, Planar functions over fields of characteristic two *Journal of Algebraic Combinatorics* 40:503-526, 2014.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something:  If $u$ is linear, then $\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(x)+u(x+a)}= \sum_{x}(-1)^{2u(x)+u(a)}=\sum_{x}(-1)^{u(a)}=2^n(-1)^{u(a)} \neq 0$ for every $a$. But I required the sum to be zero. (Note that I am *not* taking the sum over $\mathbb{F}_2$, but over the natural (or real) numbers. Perhaps I should have mentioned this explicitly in the question. Sorry if you were mislead, and thank you for the reference anyway. I am new to this field).